# Angular Http Service Unit Test Not Working With API Path Parameters - HttpTestingController expectOne

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner

I have tried below code but test getting fail, I go through several articals for the solutions, found expectOne method is not working with the url containing parameters. Need someone expert suggestion or guidance for the same.

DataService.service.ts

```
  getCountryDetails(country?: string, status?: string): Observable<Country[]> {
    // return this.http.get<Country[]>(this.config.baseUrl + '/dayone/country/india/status/confirmed');
    return this.http.get<Country[]>(`${this.config.baseUrl}/dayone/country/${country}/status/${status}`);
  }

  getDashboard(country?: string) :Observable<Dashboard[]>{
    return this.http.get<Dashboard[]>(`${this.config.baseUrl}/dayone/country/${country}`);
  }
```

Specs.ts

```
 it('Should call getDashboard', () => {

    //Arrange Data
    let country: string = 'india';
    const dummyDashboard: Dashboard[] = [
      { country: 'india', active : 20, confirmed: 50, deaths : 10, recovered : 5 },
      { country: 'india', active : 20, confirmed: 50, deaths : 10, recovered : 5 }
    ];

    //Act on method
    service.getDashboard().subscribe((data) => {
      //Assert expectation
      expect(data.length).toBe(2);
      expect(data).toEqual(dummyDashboard);
    });

    const req = httpMock.expectOne(`${config.baseUrl}/dayone/country/${country}`);
    expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');
    req.flush(dummyDashboard);
  });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnAn5.png)

Comment: What is the question? What is the expected result?

Comment: My bad, Got solved

Comment: it would be nice to describe a solution here or delete the post (: